# CakePHP get model structure in controller action

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

I want to get the current model's structure from the controller, similar to the return of `$this->modelName->read(null, id)`, but without the actual data in the record, just the structure.

Is this something Cake has built in?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of any such thing, although you can call, `$this->ModelName->schema();`  which will give output like:

```
array(
    'id' => array(
          'type' => 'integer',
           'null' => false,
           'default' => null,
           'length' => (int) 11,
           'key' => 'primary'
     )
);
```

So you could use that to write something on your own like:

```
$schema = $this->Model->schema();
$values = array_fill ( 0 , count($schema), '' );
$model = array('Model' => array_combine(array_keys($schema), $values));
```